# generate the list of all possible sequences that could be generated for the given input selection from 1 to 5

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been dabbling with some fun challenges and i came across this one that's a little frustrating to wrap my head around. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I have a list:

```
var values = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple'];
```

From that list I want to return all the possible sequences for a given input. I've tried something like this:

```js
function combinations(number) {
  const values = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple'];
  let arr = values.slice(0, number);

  if (arr.length === 1) {
    result = [...arr];
    console.log(result)
  }

  var result = arr.reduce((acc, v, i) => acc.concat(arr.slice(i + 1).map(w => v + ' ' + w)),[]);


  console.log(result);
}

combinations(2);
```

but the result only returns `['blue', 'green']` where it should return `['blue', 'green', 'bluegreen', 'greenblue']`. The solution should return at least 1 value per sequence and of course no duplicates

can someone help please!! I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example - first you find all combinations and for each combinations you calculate its permutations (so that for ["blue", "green"] you also include ["green", "blue"] and so on).

```js
var values = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple'];

function perms(items) {
  let ret = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let rest = perms(items.slice(0, i).concat(items.slice(i + 1)));

    if (!rest.length) {
      ret.push([items[i]])
    } else {
      for(let j = 0; j < rest.length; j = j + 1) {
        ret.push([items[i]].concat(rest[j]))
      }
    }
  }

  return ret;
}

function combinations(n) {
  let result = [];
  let combine = (items, other = []) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      let permutations = perms([...other, items[i]]);
      result.push(...permutations);
      
      combine(items.slice(i + 1), [...other, items[i]]);
    }
  }
  combine(values.slice(0, n));

  return result;
}

console.log(combinations(2));
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks for explaining this. I think your answer is the closest to the hint i got. the hint was "if the user inputs 5, you should get 325 sequences" and your solution does that

Answer (score 1):

```
var permArr = [],
      usedChars = [];
      const values = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple'];

    function permute(number, temp) {

      let input = temp ? temp : values.slice(0, number);

      var i, ch;
      for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        ch = input.splice(i, 1)[0];
        usedChars.push(ch);
        // if (input.length == 0) {
          permArr.push(usedChars.slice());
        // }
        temp = input;
        permute(number, input);
        input.splice(i, 0, ch);
        usedChars.pop();
      }
      return permArr  
    };

    var perm = permute(5);
    console.log(perm.length)
    console.log(perm);
```

Comment: interesting but this returns:[["blue","green"],["green","blue"]]

and I'm trying to get to:
[["blue","green"],["green","blue"], ["blue"], ["green"]] because ["blue"] and ["green"] are possible sequences

btw I'm using my example by which i have 2 elements in my array (blue and green) for simplicity sake

Comment: @ibnawfi i have fixed the above solution you can try now

Comment: @ibnawfi sorry i misunderstood a little .. can try now :)

Answer (score 0):

> "generate the list of all possible sequences that could be generated
>   for the given input selection from 1 to 5"

This is how you can do that:

```js
var values = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple'];
function combinations() {
  const values = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple'];
  let arr = values.slice(0);
  var result = arr.reduce((acc, v, i) => acc.concat(arr.slice(i+1).map(w => v + ' ' + w)),[]); // this will reduce the duplicated including the doubles (i.e. blue-blue)
  var result1 = arr.reduce((acc, v, i) => acc.concat(arr.slice(i).map(w => v + ' ' + w)),[]); // this will reduce just the duplicated (i.e. blue-green and green blue are the same here)
  var result2 = arr.reduce((acc, v, i) => acc.concat(arr.slice(0).map(w => v + ' ' + w)),[]); // this will show all possibilities  
  console.log(result);
  console.log(result1);
  console.log(result2);
}
combinations();
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: the first answer is closer to what I was looking for but i did notice in the first example, when I do 5, i only get 125 sequences where I should be getting 325. But this helps a lot on where to start :)

Comment: Because it removes the duplicated ones - but i agree that @zhuber did answer directly to your question. Glad i could help (:

Comment: No worries man, I'm super thankful for helping me out regardless !